# I opened an http website from my email, how can I know if it's safe?

Tags: account-security, security-by-design

So, I have Google alerts set for a few words, and one of these alerts had a link to the site "chatsosedi.ru" which I opened. I found  out the site isn't https. I clicked on it before realizing. Is it  safe, & what can I do to secure my email and phone now? Thanks

Comment: Https doesn't mean a site is safe, and lack of https does not mean a site is necessarily hosting malware. Do you have any indication whatsoever that anything is wrong? Did you enter any personal data or passwords on the site? If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't enter data to the site. But obviously Google alerts linked me to it thru my email.

Answer (score 1):

The "S" part of "HTTPS" only means that the connection between you and that website is encrypted. It doesn't actually have anything to do with whether or not the website can be trusted not to abuse your connection to it. Generally these days there isn't much an attacker can do to you simply by visiting a website (unless they're advanced and know some special tactics or "0day" exploits for hacking your browser.) Which is extremely unlikely. As long as you did not specifically send the website anything, or download and run anything from it, there is no reason to be concerned. I myself visited the website and noticed that it gave an error I'm familiar with, it means that it's not currently allowing access to it.

If you're still concerned and would like to continue to attempt to secure your devices, Android devices have anti-malware applications you can download. A simple search in the Play Store for such applications might help you find one. You can use these to help verify that there aren't any malicious applications running or installed on your device. To secure your email, I recommend that you change your password and check the active sessions if available, making sure you revoke any extras you see.

Edit:

After looking into it further, using a few google searches, I found that the website seems to be hosting a fake vbulletin forum where it looks like they're baiting users to click an advertising affiliate link by making it look like certain books have been found for free online.

Comment: Thanks. "After looking into it further, using a few google searches, I found that the website seems to be hosting a fake vbulletin forum where it looks like they're baiting users to click an advertising affiliate link by making it look like certain books have been found for free online." Does this mean viruses/hacking

Comment: What's the purpose of them doing that? Is it for hacking? Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, not likely. They're probably using it to get traffic and clicks so that they will get paid by affiliate programs.